# Auto Set Sub Category In Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

I want to create a new category in WordPress and set an existing category to as the subcategory of the newly created category. Is it possible for WordPress to create a category hook ??

I have tried using the create category hook but am not able to find the solution for it.